# Get attribute name or column name in JPA converter

Tags: java, jpa, converters

I have an entity with several double values where each has to be multiplied with a certain factor before storing it.

I would like to use a (single) JPA converter to multiply the attributes with the specific factor, but therefore I'd need to know which attribute I am converting within the converter function.

Is there a way to obtain the name of the attribute or the column name in the converter function or pass it to converter?

Comment: PS: I'd also be thankful for suggestions of an alternative strategy to achieve the desired behavior without breaking abstraction. Currently I'm looking into AOP, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: you can create your own annotation for the required attributes and read the metadata in the entity before persisting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your entity looks like but maybe the @Access annotation could be helpful - it can be used when you need to perform a simple transformation to the data when reading from or writing to the database (in this case the multipication happens through setter before save but getter gives the exact value stored in db). The inconvenience is that you need to add it on every setter that needs this conversion:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    private static final long FACTOR = 5;

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @Transient
    private long amount;

    // getter and setters for id and name

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(long amount) {
        this.amount = amount * FACTOR;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's more hassle than I hoped it would be, but I guess it's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using entity [lifecycle listeners](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event) instead of converters. Converters are reusable concept to map any Java datatype to a JPA type. They now nothing about your specific entity or a field. On the other hand, lifecycle listeners can be defined only for whole entity, therefore you must create listener per entity and design it in the way that the listener will know which fields to convert.

Entity listeners can be called for example before data from the entity is persisted (inserted), updated, or on the other side, also after the data is loaded back to the entity.

You would need to make use of at least [@PrePersist](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/PostPersist), which would trigger your method before your new entity is inserted into the database - in such method you have chance to multiply your data or do whatever you want. The chance is that, when the entity is read from database, you also want to convert data from database to the initial form you had before persisting. Then you should also use [@PostLoad](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/PostLoad) to convert back the data. And finally, if you want to apply the conversion again also on updates, you should use [@PreUpdate](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/PreUpdate) (you can use both `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` on the same method).

Here is an example:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
  @Id
  private long id;

  // this value will be multiplied by 10 when stored in DB
  private long size;
  // this value will be multiplied by 2 when stored in DB
  private long amount;

  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  public void convertToDbFormat() {
    size = size * 10;
    amount = amount * 2;
  }

  @PostLoad
  public void convertFromDbFormat() {
    size = size / 10;
    amount = amount / 2;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thx for the great explanation!